Can anyone tell me that how html operators will work in ckeditor?
& , < and > operators are not working. When i have entered these operators cursor moves at start of line bydefault.
I have replaced these operators with others also but didn't work and also allow this config.allowedContent = true
(CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

<CKEditor
editor={ClassicEditor}
config={{
toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', '|', 'undo', 'redo', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'Indent', 'outdent'],
}}
data={customDecode(values.message)}
onReady={(editor) => {}}
onChange={(event, editor) => {
updateLinkPreview(editor);
}}
/>
